# VBA to create a dynamic number of copies of a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to excel and have hit a wall with this issue. I am trying to copy a template table and make a dynamic number of back-to-back copies of it. I want to make the title of each table the name of a customer, which I will pull from another table. Here is what I mean:
 [image: Example]

Any help would be highly appreciated. I hope my explanation makes sense, but let me know if I need to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to place the Customer list on Column H then this would copy the tables into Sheet2 as you wanted:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row ' Count Column H as that's where the customer list is
For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to the last on column H
    NewCustomer = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value 'get the customer Name 8 being Column H
    LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find the next free row in Sheet2
    Sheet1.Range("A1:C4").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & LastRow2) 'paste the range into Sheet2
    Sheet2.Range("A" & LastRow2).Value = NewCustomer 'Replace the Customer Name
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much! Seriously appreciate it.

Comment: No worries... Just realised you wanted an option to copy n number of times... Have you got that sorted? Or should I update my answer?

Comment: I got it sorted but thanks for offering to! Really appreciate it